W3 API returning HTML instead of JSON after implementing bulk URL analysis in Laravel (Cloudflare protection issue?)
I am developing an application in Laravel that allows the user to input a URL, which is then analyzed using the W3 API at https://api.w3.org/nu. The result of the analysis is a JSON, which is formatted and displayed, or can be converted into a PDF and downloaded. The system initially worked quite well for individual URLs.
I then added the functionality for bulk URL analysis, where, if the user enters the URL https://example.com, a crawler searches for and saves all the pages on the domain (e.g., https://example.com/mission, https://example.com/contacts, etc.). After saving all the URLs found for that domain, I start the analysis, again using the W3 API.
I noticed that after some tests, the API no longer returns the JSON with the analysis results but instead the HTML page I’m trying to analyze.
It seems that W3 is using a system like Cloudflare, which implements some protection against bots. After searching online, some suggest using Puppeteer or Selenium to simulate a real browser and bypass the check, but with Puppeteer, it doesn’t seem to work, and I always get the HTML page instead of the JSON.
My IP has probably been banned due to the many attempts made during development, and indeed the analysis starts working again if I change my network.
I want to understand if there are usage limits for the service, if I need to set limits myself, if I’m doing something wrong in the implementation, or if there’s another issue.
Thanks to anyone who can help me.
